# MySql syntax error is thrown in spite of writting the correct query

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I have been trying this query in different formats yet I don't know why I get this weird error.

```
insert into details ('refno','membershipno','name','dob','year_of_passing_diploma','phone','address','email','mobileno','city','state','pincode','degree','college') values('1001','2001','ragesh','1991-06-27','2012','24423021','D1, silver star apartments sec','rageshcv@gmail.com','9840526989','chennai','tamil nadu','600020','pilot','newzeleand','98455 27/06/14','IOB chennai','Chetta kadai','nandanam','leatrher','MD','3','24405158','chennai')
```

I don't find anything wrong in this query still I am getting the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''refno','membershipno','name','dob','year_of_passing_diploma','phone','address',' at line 1
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: The query is not correct, you're quoting your field names using `'` instead of a backtick.

Comment: I vote to close these questions as a simple typographical error.

Comment: actually its a query that my code has writtern.. I am looking into the logic.. I was so dumb that i dint not look into the column and corresponding values !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use single quotes around your column identifiers. Either use ticks or nothing:

```
insert into details (refno,membershipno,name,dob,year_of_passing_diploma,phone,address,email,mobileno,city,state,pincode,degree,college) values('1001','2001','ragesh','1991-06-27','2012','24423021','D1, silver star apartments sec','rageshcv@gmail.com','9840526989','chennai','tamil nadu','600020','pilot','newzeleand','98455 27/06/14','IOB chennai','Chetta kadai','nandanam','leatrher','MD','3','24405158','chennai')
```

or

```
insert into details (`refno`,`membershipno`,`name`,`dob`,`year_of_passing_diploma`,`phone`,`address`,`email`,`mobileno`,`city`,`state`,`pincode`,`degree`,`college`) values('1001','2001','ragesh','1991-06-27','2012','24423021','D1, silver star apartments sec','rageshcv@gmail.com','9840526989','chennai','tamil nadu','600020','pilot','newzeleand','98455 27/06/14','IOB chennai','Chetta kadai','nandanam','leatrher','MD','3','24405158','chennai')
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from quoting: you have 14 columns and 23 values in your query

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes (`'`) are used to denote string literals. When refering to **columns**, you should use forward-quotes, or no quotes at all:

```
insert into details 
(refno,membershipno,name,dob,year_of_passing_diploma,phone,address,email,mobileno,city,state,pincode,degree,college)
values('1001','2001','ragesh','1991-06-27','2012','24423021','D1, silver star apartments sec','rageshcv@gmail.com','9840526989','chennai','tamil nadu','600020','pilot','newzeleand','98455 27/06/14','IOB chennai','Chetta kadai','nandanam','leatrher','MD','3','24405158','chennai')
```